# Validate loses focus on multidimensional array

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I've made a form with my input fields as:

```
name="some_name[]"
```

To get it as a multidimensional array when posting it

Using jQuery validator to validate the fields but I do have a problem with
the remote function....

my code:

```
 "some_name[]": {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    rangelength: [4, 4],
    remote:
          {
              type:'POST',
              url:plugin_path+'ajax/vogn_check.php',
          }
```

The form it self is dynamic so people can add as many rows as they want.
Here is the problem:

When filling out the field remote is attached to it works fine on the first row but when I add a second row I have to tap out of the field twice before it actually validates it.

I've tried with `.on('change', 'form', .on('keyup', 'form'`

But still have to tap out twice! Anyone who knows how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a rule on a single field with the `name` called `"some_name[]"` would work.

However, if you have multiple fields all sharing the same `name`, then it will NOT work.

This plugin uses the `name` attribute to keep track of input elements and **if you use `"some_name[]"` more than once, your rules will not work on the duplicate instances.**

One solution is to include the index within the `name`.

```
<input name="some_name[0]" ....
<input name="some_name[1]" ....
<input name="some_name[2]" ....
```

Then you can use the `.rules()` method with a "starts-with" selector and jQuery `.each()` to declare the rules on all array fields at once...

```
$('[name^="some_name"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        digits: true,
        ....
    });
});
```

> the form it self is dynamic so people can add as many rows as they want.

Since your fields are dynamically added, you'll have to dynamically declare the rules on each field using `.rules('add')` ***after*** each one is created.

*My entire answer assumes you've already properly initialized plugin using the `.validate()` method.*

Comment: Hey Sparky.

ty for the quick answer, what you say makes sense hovever i got rules for about 15 fields written this wat and they all work as they should doing the other normal way, can you explain to me why that is?.... 

only been cooding for like 6 months so i'm looking to learn as much as posible.

in advance THANKS!

Comment: @dk_skal, I can't see what you're talking about so I don't know.  Like I said, It will only work if you have ONE field with `somename[]`.

Answer (score -1):

this ended up being my answer

```
$('form#someForm').on('keyup', '.classOffSomeName', function(){
$(this).valid();
});
```

This way i'm forcing it to validate it twice in a row so by both makeing it validating on `keyup` and on `tapout` it validates it proporly.

To Sparky. no you dont need a .each for this `name="someName[]"` is enught! but on some cases you need to wrap it in a .on or .blur so it'll see the dynamic added elements, for example a dynamic field with a datepicker asociated or in this case an ajax request.

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: You are very confused. As clearly explained in my answer, an `.each()` is absolutely needed when attaching the `.rules()` method to multiple elements.  And the `.rules()` method is only needed to declare rules on elements that are created after `.validate()` is called.  **As posted, your question/answer make absolutely no sense and validation will NOT work properly**.  If you expect to get an accurate solution, then you need to write a good question including any relevant code... since you never mentioned using a date-picker in your question, this answer is useless to everyone else.